# Esconder e mostrar senha com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web, webforms

Estou tentando fazer o efeito de ao clicar no input check Mostrar Senha a senha digitada pelo usuário apareça para ele visualizar.
Semelhante ao desse formulário do Google.
O meu html está assim:

```html
<div class="div-body">
    <h1 id="titulo-login">LOGIN</h1>
        <form class="div-container">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="div-container-inputs">
                    <div class="div-box-inputs">
                        <div class="div-cont-inputs">
                        <legend>Matricula:</legend> 
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Ex: 20201SI0068" class="input"> 
                            <legend>Senha:</legend> 
                            <input type="password" placeholder="No mín. 8 caracteres, . , ; @ # % e etc" class="input">
                            <br>               
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="check" checked="checked" />
                                <span>Mostrar senha</span>
                            </label> 
                            <label class="butao">
                                <div class="div-butao">
                                    <button id="butao-entrar">Entrar</button>
                                </div>
                            </label>                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
         </fieldset> 
     </form>
</div>
```

Eu quero que quando o check estiver checked apareça a senha, mas até agora ainda não consegui desenvolver.

Comment: Basta você trocar o `type="password"` para `type="text"` quando quiser mostrar e reverter o processo quando quiser esconder.

Comment: mas @Carolina posta teu js... não é só alterar **password** para **text**, tem ação do checkbox.

Answer (score -2):

```
<script>
  let btn = document.querySelector('.eye')
  btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let input = document.querySelector('#input-password-wrapper')
    if (input.getAttribute('type') == 'password') {
      input.setAttribute('type', 'text')
    } else {
      input.setAttribute('type', 'password')
    }
  })
</script>
```